# Struggling to test component with RTL that uses a useContext hook

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library, react-context

I have a test like so:

```
const CurrentViewContext = createContext('');
test('Renders the texts: My Services', () => {
  render(
    <CurrentViewContext.Provider
      value={{
        setCurrentView: jest.fn(),
        setViewData: jest.fn(),
      }}
    >
      <MyServices />,
    </CurrentViewContext.Provider>,
  );
})
```

My component looks like this:

```
import { useState, useEffect, useContext } from 'react';    
const MyServicesListView: React.FC<MyServicesListViewProps> = ({ searching }) => {
      const { setCurrentView, setViewData } = useContext(CurrentViewContext);
      /* Ommitted code... */
    })
```

Whenever I run my tests I get this error:

```
 TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'setCurrentView' of '(0 , _react.useContext)(...)' as it is null.

      19 |
      20 | const MyServicesListView: React.FC<MyServicesListViewProps> = ({ searching }) => {
    > 21 |   const { setCurrentView, setViewData } = useContext(CurrentViewContext);
```

index.tsx (renders Myservices but the test renders MyServices directly but this is where the Context is created in the actually App [Which I iam trying to recreate in my test])

export const CurrentViewContext = createContext(null);

```
const MyservicesIndex: FC<Props> = () => {
  const [currentView, setCurrentView] = useState('Home');
  const [viewData, setViewData] = useState({});

  const renderComponent = () => {
    switch (currentView) {
      case 'Home':
        return <MyServices />;
      case 'PrivateApi':
        return <PrivateApiServices />;
      case 'DataMesh':
        return (
          <>
            <DataMeshServices />
            <CatalogFooter />
          </>
        );
      case 'ARR':
        return <MSAlgoRiskReport />;
      default:
        return <MyServices />;
    }
  };

  return (
    <CurrentViewContext.Provider
      value={{
        currentView,
        setCurrentView,
        viewData,
        setViewData,
      }}
    >
      <>{renderComponent()}</>
    </CurrentViewContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default MyservicesIndex;
```

(MyServices renders MyServicesListView)

Do you see anything thats an issue here? From my research I am doing everything correctly...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React jest testing error - object of useContext not defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66856814/react-jest-testing-error-object-of-usecontext-not-defined)

Comment: I think I've seen this one before, the answer mentions to wrap my app in a provider:
`render(<UserProvider><App /></UserProvider>`
and thats what I do isn't it?
`<CurrentViewContext.Provider> ... </CurrentViewContext.Provider>`

Comment: `MyServicesListView` imports the context. Mind sharing more of your code? Hard to say at this point

Comment: Not sure what you are looking for specifically, alot of the code seems irrelevant to this issue but I added a new file called index.tsx to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the `useContext` is returning `null` instead of the expected `value`.

So, try use the *react-testing-library*'s `render` to wrap your component with the [context](https://testing-library.com/docs/example-react-context/). This may useful when want to test the components in a way that resembles how they're used in application.

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import { CurrentViewContext } from './yourContextPath';
import MyServices from './yourComponentPath';

function renderWithContext(ui, {providerProps, ...renderOptions}) {
 return render(
   <CurrentViewContext.Provider {...providerProps}>{ui}</CurrentViewContext.Provider>,
   renderOptions,
 );
}

test('Renders the texts: My Services', () => {
 renderWithContext(<MyServices />, {providerProps: { value: { setCurrentView: jest.fn(), setViewData: jest.fn() }}});
 // your assertions here
});
```

Comment: Hey, thanks, this worked! How come using the render option is needed? Doesn't it just wrap the component like I did manually? Or does it do something extra? Gave you the bounty/answer